# What should we do about the questions that is not really about learning process, but about the effect of it to the learners?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

So far, I have noticed some questions that are not really related to the process of learning a language, but effect of it to the learners. Three examples:

- [Does learning a second language happen in the same part of the brain as learning a first language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/205/168) (well-received)
- [Why does learning languages help with aversing dementia?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/494/168) (closed)
- [Is there any evidence that vocabulary level is a good measure for predicting success?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/682/168) (closed)

Is this kind of question on-topic? For the first two questions, I don't see any different between them (in fact they are asked from one user, tagged with only one tag: neurology), yet received two different altitudes. The third question is mine, and I would argue that if we are fine with questions ask for neurology aspect of the learners, then we will be fine with questions ask for the economic aspect.

Comment: I don't see a common thread through these questions. They are distinct, and each was handled as it was for different reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the response is as mixed as it may seem; we're dealing with three different types of questions:

### [Does learning a second language happen in the same part of the brain as learning a first language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/205/168) ✓ On-Topic

I agree that this question is on-topic, as it clearly asks about language learning and its associated cognitive functions.

### [Why does learning languages help with aversing dementia?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/494/168) ✗ Off-Topic

As [Robert Cartaino](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/1/robert-cartaino) said in [his comment](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/494/why-does-learning-languages-help-with-aversing-dementia#comment918_494) about closing the question:

> ...the neuroscience of dementia is a subject of [cognitive sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) or possibly [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/). This question doesn't really deal with expertise or learning techniques of language acquisition as intended by this site.

This is mostly a *good question* because it is well-researched and specific, the problem is that this question is *more about dementia than language learning*, and LL.SE isn't the proper site to ask about dementia.

### [Is there any evidence that vocabulary level is a good measure for predicting success?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/682/168) ✗ Unclear

This question is not so off-topic as it is unclear, as the close reason adequately denotes. The quote is ambiguous, and the final question is not specific, let alone specifically about language learning and/or its associated processes. In addition, "success" is subjective.

---

I believe that *in general* **questions about the effect of language learning to the learners are on-topic**, of course, depending on the question.

Answer (score -1):

There's a very fine borderline between **about language learning** and **not about language learning.**

I would say the first question is barely on-topic, as it seems to be about the actual process of learning languages, which is actually on-topic.

On the other hand, both of the other questions have to do with the **effects** of language learning, not the process itself. You could've just as easily replaced language learning and vocabulary level in the second and third question, with something like *Why does having brown hair help with aversing demntia?* and *Is there any evidence that having blue eyes is a good measure for predicting success?*

Both of the other questions don't have to directly do with language learning, rather, **they have to do with other factors that merely involve language learning**, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?